# Problem in Xamarin.Forms with GetAsync(url) and JsonConvert

Tags: c#, json, api, xamarin.forms, json.net

This case should be very simple, but I have a little bug that I don't know how to solve. I'm working with a Xamarin.Forms app that does some API calls to a localhost API running in my PC. This is the main part of the API call:

```
try
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    client.MaxResponseContentBufferSize = BUFFER_SIZE;
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(CULTURE_ID, "es");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(VALUE, LAST_WEEK_VALUE);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue(BEARER, token);

    var content = new StringContent("", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, APPLICATION_JSON);

    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url);
    var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    List<SubProductParser> prices;
    try
    {
        prices = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<SubProductParser>>(result);
    }
    catch
    {
        // exception missin the final character in JSON "]"
    }

    return prices.ElementAt(0);
}
catch
{
    return null;
}
```

The content of the `result` variable before trying to do the deserialize:
[image: Variable result content]

As you can see is not a valid JSON format, is strange because as you can see in the next screenshot when I do the same API call with POSTMAN is working always perfectly, but I don't know why sometimes doesn't receive all the JSON content when I do the call in the app.

[image: API call with POSTMAN]

Any idea, seeing the variable `result` content in debug, sometimes doesn't have the final character of the JSON "]", the API call is made after a button tapped in this way:

```
private async void Handle_Item_Tapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
{
    var selected = e.Item as ProductParser;
    var lastPrice= await ApiConnector.GetLastWeekSubProductPrices(
        App.ViewModel.LoginViewModel.SesionToken,
        subCatViewModel.Selected.ProductId,
        subCatViewModel.Selected.Id);
    await subCatViewModel.IsFavorite();
    subCatViewModel.BarViewModel.Selected = selected;
    subCatViewModel.BarViewModel.Categories = _categories;
    subCatViewModel.LinearViewModel.Selected = selected;
    subCatViewModel.LinearViewModel.Categories = _categories;
    await Navigation.PushAsync(new Graphs(subCatViewModel));
}
```

The API functions that implement this API call, the API is developed in Larvael using php.  I tried to simplify them as much as possible:

```
public static function getLastWeekPrices($cultureId)
{
  self::initialize();
  $year = self::getLastYear();
  $prejson = json_encode(DB::table('product')
  ->join(SOME_CONDITIONS..)
  ...
  ->where(SOME_CONDITIONS..)
  ...
  ->select(SOME_ROWS)
  ->get());

  $currentWeek = self::getCurrentWeek();
  $json_decoded = json_decode($prejson, true);
  $json_final = array();
  foreach ($json_decoded as $slider_value)
  {

      $max_week= DB::table(SOME_CONDITIONS)
      ->max(SOME_CONDITIONS);

      $last_week_price = json_encode(SOME_CONDITIONS)
      ...
      ->get());

      ...
      //ADDING SOME VALUES TO $slider_value
      ...
      array_push($json_final, $slider_value);
  }
  return json_encode($json_final);
}

public static function subProductsPricesQuery($id, $subId, $cultureId, $values)
{
  self::initialize();

  if (self::doesCultureExist($cultureId)){
    if ($values == self::LAST_WEEK) {
      $json = self::getLastWeekSubProductPrices($id, $subId, $cultureId);
    }
    ....
  }
}

public function FunctionCalledInAPIRoute(Request $request, $id, $subId)
{
  try{
      $user = JWTAuth::parseToken()->toUser();
      $json = DatabaseQuerys::subProductsPricesQuery($id, $subId, $request->header("cultureId"),   $request->header("value"));
      return self::jsonIsEmpty($json);
  }catch(JWTException $e){
      return $this->respondInternalError("Any token found!");
  }
}

public static function jsonIsEmpty($products)
{
  self::initialize();
  $initial = $products[0] === "[" ? TRUE : FALSE;
  $final = $products[1] === "]" ? TRUE : FALSE ;


  if (strlen($products) === 0 || ($initial == TRUE && $final == TRUE))
  {
    header('Content-type:application/json;charset=utf-8');
    return (new self)->respondNotFound("Any result found in this category");
  } else {
    header('Content-type:application/json;charset=utf-8');
    return $products;
  }
}
```

The JsonIsEmpty is a little method that I create to control if the database return something, if not as the functions return json_encoder($array), always will be [].
The content of the variable result when receives the faulty JSON:

```
  [
    {
        "id": 19,
        "name": "Conejo de más de 2125 gr",
        "units": "€/Kg",
        "price": "1.91",
        "week": 10,
        "year": 2019,
        "last_price": "1.79",
        "difference": "0.12",
        "arrow": "up_arrow.png"
    }
```

As you can see is missing the closing "]".
I implemented a little test to see if the app is working fine, the test function and the function that calls it:

```
     public static function jsonIsEmptyTest($products)
      {
        self::initialize();
        $initial = $products[0] === "[" ? TRUE : FALSE;
        $final = $products[1] === "]" ? TRUE : FALSE ;


        if (strlen($products) === 0 || ($initial == FALSE && $final == FALSE))
        {
          return 1;
        } else {
          return 0;
        }
      }

    public static function the foo(....)
    {
          $correct = 0;
          $wrong = 0;
          for($x = 0; $x < 1000; $x++)
          {
            $json = DatabaseQuerys::subProductsPricesQuery($id, $subId, $request->header("cultureId"),   $request->header("value"));
            print_r($json);
            print_r("\n\n");
            $result = JsonController::jsonIsEmptyTest($json);
            if($result == 0)
            {
              $correct = $correct + 1;
            }
            if($result == 1)
            {
              $wrong = $wrong + 1;
            }

          }
          print_r("Correct: ");
          print_r($correct);
          print_r("\n");
          print_r("Wrong: ");
          print_r($wrong);
          exit();
    }
```

Doing the API call with postman the result is:

[image: Result]

Comment: Postman has a job to display response whether your json response is right or wrong. But for `JsonConvert` it needs a valid json but if your json is not valid then it throws an exception

Comment: Can you please show us the code, where is the part of API that generates the JSON? This error occurs very likely because of that.

Comment: @Tatranskymedved I tried to simplify it, do you see any problem with the return of the main functions json_encode(array()) in php?

Comment: Ok, could you please also add the string output from VS during debug (the faulty one)? There might be something that we don't see in the img.

Comment: First idea is to write simple check on the server side similar to `jsonIsEmpty` method -> check if JSON is parseable & properly closed everytime. This will confirm the issue is not within API and you should check next stage. That is downloading the string & parsing into JSON. There shouldn't not occur error during transmit. Write some test to download several (up to 10000x) strings & confirm that all are completely the same, localy this should be pretty fast.

Comment: @Tatranskymedved I just added the faulty one, I will try to do the test

Comment: @Tatranskymedved I just implemented the little test and is working always fine in the server side,  it is so strange,  I know it shouldn't occur error during the transmit, how should I debug it now in Xamarin.Forms?

Comment: @notarealgreal In forms ,If this `prices = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<SubProductParser>>(result);`  not null data no problem,else need to check data.

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT data is not null and I have the described problem, the JSON is not full. Any idea?

Comment: @notarealgreal I think data not full should not be result from Client's Deserialize Problem.If server has no problem,it's strange.If have other ideas ,will share here.